# MHL with the Nexus One

Tags: android, usb, driver, nexus-one, screen-grab

I'm interested in using MHL (Mobile High-definition Link) with my old and rooted Nexus One. Is that possible?

From my point of view I'd assume that MHL might be realized by using a special driver/firmware or does MHL require a special chip as well?

I haven't found that much information on that topic so far. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but just a tiny additional data-point:

As a quick test, I tried plugging the MHL adaptor I just received for my Samsung Galaxy S3 into my old Google Nexus One, and the connector doesn't even want to fit, and there was no response from the phone or the TV.

I have read that Samsung's MHL is a little bit non-standard, so this wasn't much of a surprise.